# How to avoid Matlab to convert doubles to integers while putting those doubles to a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, rounding

Hi I am trying to put double values into a vector but when I display this vector, I see that double values I put inside are converted to integers. How can I avoid this?

I checked the values of teta and they are as expected (ie. 1.802, 1.688), but in the matrix `x`, the values are all 1's.

```
SerialPort = 'COM23';
s = serial(SerialPort, 'BaudRate', 115200);
fopen(s);

n = 1;


while n<200
    dis = fscanf(s,'d',2);
    ang = fscanf(s,'d',3);
    intDis = str2double(dis);
    intAng = str2double(ang);
    teta = pi/6 +(intAng-100)*pi/300;
    x(n) = teta
    y(n) = intDis;

    n = n+1;
end


%polar(x,y)
fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @runo 'when I display this vector' which vector? Do you mean if you look at it in the variable explorer, or how do you display it? It would be helpful if you provide a sample of whatever is read-out at the serial port and explain your question in more detail

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can happen is if `x` was declared as an integer (or maybe logical?) before the script started. You should always initialize all variables, always, to avoid unexpected errors: add `x=[];` to your script before the loop.

But your loop runs exactly 200 iterations, so you know the size `x` will have at the end. You can preallocate:

```
x = zeros(200,1);
```

I also recommend that you look into the syntax of the `for` loop, as that would be simpler in this case than `while`.